# Slick 3.3.0 and custom "def *" projection

Tags: scala, slick

I am using slick 3.3.0 with Scala 2.12.8 and a custom `def *` method for a case class with more than 22 fields. I still get `too many elements for tuple: 23, allowed: 22`

What am I doing wrong?

```
class DealerTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Dealer](tag, "dealer") {

  import CustomConverters._

  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def sellId = column[String]("sell_id", O.Unique)

  def customerId = column[Int]("customer_id", O.Unique)

  def fake = column[Boolean]("fake", O.Default(false))

  def companyName = column[String]("company_name")

  def district = column[String]("district")

  def street = column[String]("street")

  def postcode = column[String]("postcode")

  def city = column[String]("city")

  def country = column[Country]("country")

  def firstName = column[String]("first_name")

  def lastName = column[String]("last_name")

  def gender = column[Option[Gender]]("gender")

  def email = column[String]("email")

  def phone = column[String]("phone")

  def mobilePhone = column[String]("mobile_phone")

  def subscriptionEndDate = column[Option[LocalDate]]("subscription_end_date")

  def culture = column[Culture]("culture")

  def rating = column[Float]("rating")

  def minPrice = column[Option[Int]]("min_price")

  def maxPrice = column[Option[Int]]("max_price")

  def createdAt = column[ZonedDateTime]("created_at")

  def updatedAt = column[ZonedDateTime]("updated_at")

  def * =
    (
      id,
      sellId,
      customerId,
      fake,
      companyName,
      district.?,
      street,
      postcode,
      city,
      country,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      gender,
      email,
      phone,
      mobilePhone.?,
      subscriptionEndDate,
      culture,
      rating.?,
      minPrice,
      maxPrice,
      createdAt.?,
      updatedAt.?
    ) <> ((Dealer.apply _).tupled, Dealer.unapply)
}

final case class Dealer(id: Int,
                        sellId: String,
                        customerId: Int,
                        fake: Boolean = false,
                        companyName: String,
                        district: Option[String],
                        street: String,
                        postcode: String,
                        city: String,
                        country: Country,
                        firstName: String,
                        lastName: String,
                        gender: Option[Gender],
                        email: String,
                        phone: String,
                        mobilePhone: Option[String],
                        subscriptionEndDate: Option[LocalDate],
                        culture: Culture,
                        rating: Option[Float],
                        minPrice: Option[Int],
                        maxPrice: Option[Int],
                        createdAt: Option[ZonedDateTime] = None,
                        updatedAt: Option[ZonedDateTime] = None)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no tuples with more than 22 elements in Scala 2.12.8.

And here `def * = 
     (
      id,
      sellId, ...`
you're trying to create such tuple.

[22 Column limit for procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399431/22-column-limit-for-procedures/)

[Slick - Update full object or more than 22 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320712/slick-update-full-object-or-more-than-22-columns)

https://lihaimei.wordpress.com/2016/03/30/slick-1-fix-more-than-22-columns-case/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand. What would be the most straightforward way with least boilerplate code and least necessary modifications to the mapped case class (Dealer in the example) to implement ```def *``` then. Which way would you recommend?